# Hyper Terminal is showing ~% instead of $

Tags: macos, terminal, hyperterminal

After restarting my Mac which is running on MacOs Catalina 10.15.3, Hyper shows

`username@MacBook-Air ~ %`

instead of the regular $. Why is that and what does the percentage symbol mean?

Im also not able to check the version of my hyper using the command line, see below:

username@MacBook-Air ~ % hyper --version

The option "version" is unknown. Here's a list of all available options:

Usage: hyper [options] [command]

Commands:

```
<default>                    Launch Hyper
d, docs, h, home             Open the npm page of a plugin
help                         Display help
i, install                   Install a plugin
ls, list                     List installed plugins
lsr, list-remote, ls-remote  List plugins available on npm
s, search                    Search for plugins on npm
u, uninstall, rm, remove     Uninstall a plugin
version                      Show the version of hyper
```

Options:

```
-h, --help     Output usage information
-v, --verbose  Verbose mode (disabled by default)
```

Thanks!

Comment: To check the version you should type `hyper version` not `hyper --version`, remove that from your question please.

Answer (score 11):

The percent sign does not have a particular *meaning*.

It has not much to do with Hyper Terminal, but with the shell you use (bash or zsh).

Usually bash uses `$`, whereas zsh uses `%`.

Take a look at: [Google: bash+zsh+prompt](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash%20zsh%20prompt)

Answer (score 3):

Found this answer on medium.com's article "Customize the MacOS Terminal":

"As of 2019, macOS Catalina has adopted Z Shell, or zsh for short, as the default login shell. Z Shell is a Unix shell that acts as an interactive login shell and command line interpreter for shell scripting."

https://medium.com/dev-genius/customize-the-macos-terminal-zsh-4cb387e4f447